# Смещение координат клика JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при «клике» по странице появлялся `DIV`.

Когда я делаю «клик», то `DIV` появляется **рядом**, не в месте «клика», а в стороне, по диагонали на расстоянии 5-10 пикселей.

Что делать?

```
<style>
#promo_point{
width: 5px;
height: 5px;
background-color: #ffffff;
position: absolute;
}
</style>
<td id="b1">
<script>
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
$("#b1").append("<div id='promo_point'></div>");
$("#promo_point").css("background-color","red");
$("#promo_point").css("top",e.pageY+"px");
$("#promo_point").css("left",e.pageX+"px");
}, false);

</script></td>
```

Comment: Приведите рабочий пример, чтобы была понятная вся ваша разметка, тогда посмотрим.

Comment: Для того, чтобы на вопрос можно было ответить, добавьте **весь** относящийся к проблеме код и сообщения об ошибках в сам вопрос. [ask], [как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Прибавьте нужное смешение к координатам.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    $("#b1").append("<div id='promo_point'></div>");
    $("#promo_point").css("background-color","red");
    $("#promo_point").css("top",(e.pageY-3)+"px");
    $("#promo_point").css("left",(e.pageX-3)+"px");
}, false);
```

Уменьшаем обращение к `DOM` и делаем один `css` вызов:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var elem = $("<div id='promo_point'></div>");
    elem.css({
        "background-color": "red",
        "top": (e.pageY-3)+"px",
        "left": (e.pageX-3)+"px"
    });
    $("#b1").append(elem);
}, false);
```

В вашей версии создается много `div`, но только один первый подсвечивается css.

Если вы хотите, чтобы точка оставалась одна, то нужно очищать:

```
var container = $("#b1");
container.html('');
container.append(elem);
```

Замечание: `window.addEventListener` работает не во всех браузерах. JQuery или так:

```
function addEvent(obj, type, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener)
        obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    else if (obj.attachEvent)
        obj.attachEvent('on' + type, function() { return fn.apply(obj, [window.event]);});
}
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.

Comment: @PeterOlson обновил ответ